# XAML Binding Groups

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to make a binding group to calculate if a row is valid based on 3 textboxes in a datagrid.

I have created a ValidationRule class and then in my datagrid I have:

```
       <DataGrid.BindingGroup>
          <BindingGroup Name="RowBindingGroup">
             <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                <util:MinMaxParValidationRule ValidationStep="CommittedValue" />
             </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
          </BindingGroup>
       </DataGrid.BindingGroup>
```

and

```
<TextBox.Text>
   <Binding Path="ParStockLevel" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" BindingGroupName="RowBindingGroup" />
</TextBox.Text>
```

My validation rule class looks like

```
 public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
  {
     ValidationResult result = ValidationResult.ValidResult;
     BindingGroup bindingGroup = (BindingGroup)value;

     StockInformationDVM row = (StockInformationDVM)bindingGroup.Items[0];
```

Now when I run the application the value that comes into the validation rule class is always the first rowin my datagrid, never the row that is being validated (unless ofc you are validating the first row!)

I havent done this before and the examples I find arent using MVVM so there may be issues there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying you binding group as `DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup` instead of `DataGrid.BindingGroup`:

```
<DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
   <BindingGroup>
      <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
         <util:MinMaxParValidationRule ValidationStep="CommittedValue" />
      </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
   </BindingGroup>
</DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
```

And in this case you actually can omit specifying the name for your binding group. It will automatically be used for all bindings in a row.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Unfortunately it doesnt work quite right though, it seems that bindingGroup.Items[0]; is now not the type of item the row is bound to but rather the ViewModel which launched the ViewModel the datagrid is in

Comment: @Purplegoldfish - This is strange because I just created a test project and everything works great... Do you use `DataGridTemplateColumn` for bindings? Please double-check that rows indeed have an object of type `StockInformationDVM` as their `DataContext`.

Comment: I am using DataGridTemplateColumn for the columns and the ItemsSource is deffinately bound to a StockInformationDVM. I dont have DataContext="" specified on the datagrid though, I assumed having the ItemsSource set would be sufficient.

Comment: @Purplegoldfish - `ItemsSource` should be sufficient for this. I ran out of ideas why it doesn't work in your case...

Comment: Thanks for the help, I guess the solution will turn up eventually though I'm out of ideas on this one too